# Register shiny checkboxInput value on DT

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny, dt

I am able to embed checkbox in each cell of a DT column from reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48854547/r-shiny-how-to-make-datatable-react-to-checkboxes-in-datatable).

Imagine I have a dataframe with a logical column named "value" containing some TRUE values, and I want the checkbox in "value_check" column to appear as checked for those that are TRUE upon app start, like shown below: How would I do so?

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

df <- data.frame(item = c("a", "b", "c"), value = c(TRUE, NA, NA))

shinyInput <- function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
  inputs <- character(len)
  for (i in seq_len(len)) {
    inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), label = NULL, ...))
  }
  inputs
}

## obtaining checkbox value
shinyValue = function(id, len) { 
  unlist(lapply(seq_len(len), function(i) { 
    value = input[[paste0(id, i)]] 
    if (is.null(value)) FALSE else value 
  })) 
} 

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$tbl <- renderDT(server = FALSE, escape = FALSE, editable = TRUE, options = list(
    dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE,
    preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
    drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
  ), {
    df$value_check <- shinyInput(checkboxInput, nrow(df), "check")
    df
    }
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("tbl")
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought I had a solution but now I'm afraid I misunderstood your question. With the code below, the values in the `value` column are updated according to the status of the corresponding checkbox in the `value_check` column.

```
js <- c(
  "$('[id^=check]').on('click', function(){",
  "  var id = this.getAttribute('id');",
  "  var i = parseInt(/check(\\d+)/.exec(id)[1]);",
  "  var value = $(this).prop('checked');",
  "  var cell = table.cell(i-1, 2).data(value).draw();",
  "})"
)
```

then

```
  output$tbl <- renderDT(server = FALSE, escape = FALSE, editable = TRUE, 
                         callback = JS(js),
                         options = list(
                           dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE,
                           preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
                           drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
                         ), {
                           df$value_check <- shinyInput(checkboxInput, nrow(df), "check")
                           df
                         }
  )
```

[image]

But now I understand that you ask for the "converse" : check the checkbox according to the value in the `value` column. Right ? However don't you need the above as well ?

Then, to answer your question as I understand it now, I would do:

```
shinyCheckboxes <- function(len, id, checked){
  inputs <- character(len)
  for (i in seq_len(len)) {
    inputs[i] <- as.character(checkboxInput(paste0(id, i), label=NULL, 
                                            value = checked[i]))
  }
  inputs
}
```

then

```
checked <- sapply(df$value, isTRUE)
df$value_check <- shinyCheckboxes(nrow(df), "check", checked)
```

Is it what you want ?

Comment: Thank you so much! It is exactly what I wanted. Regarding your initial solution - I previously managed to save the T/F value to dataframe, but the "value" column didn't change simultaneously with user input but only after page refresh. So both your solutions are very helpful.