# R Shiny update textInput fields' in DT on changing variable selection

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, dt, textinput

I am building an app where the user loads an `.RData` data set (the file can be downloaded from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3e1tn9eqkmm44qt/test1.RData?dl=0)) and selects variable from a list (`DT`), moves it to another list (also `DT`) and then the available factor levels are displayed in a third `DT` underneath. This third `DT` also has a column of dynamically generated `textInput` fields which match the number of available factor levels for the variable where the user can add new values for the existing factor levels. The entered values are stored in a `reactiveValues` object. For now the object is just printed in the R console. The app looks like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(data.table)
library(shinyFiles)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shinyFilesButton(id = "recodeChooseSrcFile", label = "Choose data file", title = "Navigate and select a file", multiple = FALSE),
  
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 6,
           DTOutput(outputId = "recodeAllAvailableVars"),
    ),
    column(width = 1, align = "center",
           br(), br(), br(), br(), br(), br(), br(), br(), br(), br(),
           uiOutput(outputId = "recodeArrowSelVarsRight"),
           br(), br(),
           uiOutput(outputId = "recodeArrowSelVarsLeft"),
    ),
    column(width = 5,
           DTOutput(outputId = "recodeVarsSelection"),
    ),
    br(), br()
  ),
  
  br(), br(),
  DTOutput(outputId = "recodeScheme")
  
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  available.volumes <- getVolumes()()
  
  file.var.recode <- reactiveValues(loaded = NULL, var.levels = NULL)
  
  # Select file and extract the variables.
  shinyFileChoose(input, "recodeChooseSrcFile", roots = available.volumes, filetype = list(RData = "RData"))
  
  observeEvent(eventExpr = input$recodeChooseSrcFile, {
    
    if(length(parseFilePaths(available.volumes, input$recodeChooseSrcFile)$datapath) > 0) {
      
      file.var.recode$loaded <- get(load(parseFilePaths(available.volumes, input$recodeChooseSrcFile)$datapath))
      
      file.var.recode$var.levels <- Filter(Negate(is.null), lapply(X = file.var.recode$loaded, FUN = function(i) {
        if(is.null(attr(x = i, which = "levels"))) {
          NULL
        } else {
          attr(x = i, which = "levels")
        }
      }))
      
      file.var.recode$loaded <- data.table(Variables = names(file.var.recode$loaded),
      
      order_col = 1:ncol(file.var.recode$loaded))
    }
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
  
  observe({
    
    var.props.initial.available.vars <- data.table(Variables = as.character(), order_col = as.numeric())
    var.props.initial.selected.vars <- data.table(Variables = as.character(), order_col = as.numeric())
    
    recodeAllVars <- reactiveValues(recodeAvailVars = var.props.initial.available.vars, recodeSelectedVars = var.props.initial.selected.vars)
    
    # Observe if the file is loaded, and if yes, update the table of available variables.
    observe({
      if(!is.null(file.var.recode$loaded)) {
        recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars <- file.var.recode$loaded
      }
    })
    
    # Render the arrow buttons for selecting the variables.
    output$recodeArrowSelVarsRight <- renderUI({
      if(is.null(file.var.recode$loaded)) {
        return(NULL)
      } else {
        actionButton(inputId = "recodeArrowSelVarsRight", label = NULL, icon("angle-right"), width = "50px")
      }
    })
    
    output$recodeArrowSelVarsLeft <- renderUI({
      if(is.null(file.var.recode$loaded)) {
        return(NULL)
      } else {
        actionButton(inputId = "recodeArrowSelVarsLeft", label = NULL, icon("angle-left"), width = "50px")
      }
    })
    
    # Render the data table with the available variables.
    output$recodeAllAvailableVars <- renderDT({

      if(is.null(file.var.recode$loaded)) {
        return(NULL)
      } else {
        setkeyv(x = recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars, cols = "order_col")
      }

    },
    caption = "Available variables",
    rownames = FALSE,
    colnames = c("Names", "sortingcol"),
    options = list(
      ordering = FALSE,
      columnDefs = list(list(visible = FALSE, targets = 1))
    ))
    
    
    
    # Render the table with the selected variables.
    output$recodeVarsSelection <- renderDT({
      if(is.null(file.var.recode$loaded)) {
        return(NULL)
      } else {
        setkeyv(x = recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars, cols = "order_col")
      }
    },
    
    caption = "Available variables",
    rownames = FALSE,
    colnames = c("Names", "sortingcol"),
    options = list(
      ordering = FALSE,
      columnDefs = list(list(visible = FALSE, targets = 1))
      
    ))
    
    # Observe the events of moving variables from available to selected.
    observeEvent(input$recodeArrowSelVarsRight, {
      req(input$recodeAllAvailableVars_rows_selected)
      recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars <- rbind(isolate(recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars), recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars[input$recodeAllAvailableVars_rows_selected, , drop = F])
      recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars <- recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars[complete.cases(recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars[ , "Variables"]), , drop = FALSE]
      recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars <- isolate(recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars[-input$recodeAllAvailableVars_rows_selected, , drop = F])
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$recodeArrowSelVarsLeft, {
      req(input$recodeVarsSelection_rows_selected)
      recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars <- rbind(isolate(recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars), recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars[input$recodeVarsSelection_rows_selected, , drop = F])
      recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars <- recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars[complete.cases(recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars[ , "Variables"]), , drop = FALSE]
      recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars <- isolate(recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars[-input$recodeVarsSelection_rows_selected, , drop = F])
    })
    
    # Render the table with the text inputs.
    initial.recode.new.values <- reactiveValues(values = NULL)
    
    entered.new.values <- reactiveValues(values = NULL)
    
    new.recoding.values <- reactiveValues(values = NULL)
    
    shinyInput <- function(obj) {
      tmp <- unlist(lapply(X = seq_along(obj), FUN = function(i) {
        i <- paste0(textInput(inputId = paste0("numinp", i), label = NULL, value = NULL, width = "50px"))
      }))
      return(tmp)
    }
    
    shinyValue <- function(id, len) {
      unlist(lapply(seq_len(len), function(i) {
        input[[paste0(id, i)]]
      }))
    }
    
    # Observe the changes in user selection and update the reactive values from above.
    observe({
      
      initial.recode.new.values$values <- unlist(unique(file.var.recode$var.levels[recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars[ , Variables]]))
      
      entered.new.values$values <- data.table(
        V1 = initial.recode.new.values$values,
        V2 = initial.recode.new.values$values,
        V3 = rep(x = "->", times = length(initial.recode.new.values$values)),
        V4 = shinyInput(unlist(unique(file.var.recode$var.levels[recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars[ , Variables]])))
      )
      
      new.recoding.values$values <- shinyValue(id = "numinp", len = length(unlist(unique(file.var.recode$var.levels[recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars[ , Variables]]))))
      
    })
    
    # Render the table with available levels and empty input fields where the user can enter his desired new values.
    output$recodeScheme <- renderDT({
      
      if(!is.null(unlist(unique(file.var.recode$var.levels[recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars[ , Variables]])))) {
        entered.new.values$values
      } else {
        return(NULL)
      }
      
    },
    rownames = FALSE,
    colnames = c("Available variable values", "Old", "->", "New"),
    class = "cell-border stripe;compact cell-border;",
    selection="none",
    escape = FALSE,
    options = list(
      pageLength = 1500,
      dom = 'BRrt',
      rowCallback = JS("function(r,d) {$(r).attr('height', '40px')}"),
      preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
      drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')))
    
    observe({
      print(new.recoding.values$values)
    })
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It all works fine when the variable is selected, the newly entered values are immediately updated and shown in the console on every key stroke. However, if the user decides to remove the variable from the `DT` of selected ones, the `new.recoding.values$values` reactive value becomes immediately `NULL` (as intended), but when another variable is added to the `DT` of selected variables, the old values for the previous variable are immediately brought back and never get updated. In addition, if the new variable has more levels than the first entered, then the last is possible to update, but not the previous ones (try entering `ASBG03`, then replace it with `ASBG04` to see what I mean).

I don't really understand why is this happening. What I tried so far is to explicitly set the `new.recoding.values$values` to `NULL` in:

1.The observer where it is generated, before the `shinyValue` function is ran.

2.In the `observeEvent` where the right arrow button is pressed, i.e.:

```
observeEvent(input$recodeArrowSelVarsLeft, {
  req(input$recodeVarsSelection_rows_selected)
  recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars <- rbind(isolate(recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars), 
  recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars[input$recodeVarsSelection_rows_selected, , drop = F])
  recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars <- recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars[complete.cases(recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars[ , "Variables"]), , drop = FALSE]
  recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars <- isolate(recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars[-input$recodeVarsSelection_rows_selected, , drop = F])
  new.recoding.values$values <- NULL
})
```

**UPDATE:**

3.Following Tonio Liebrand's advice, I tried to update the text inputs as follow (added just after rendering the last `DT`):

```
observe({
      if(nrow(entered.new.values$values) == 0) {
        lapply(seq_len(length(unlist(unique(file.var.recode$var.levels[recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars[ , Variables]])))), function(i) {
          updateTextInput(session,
                          input[[paste0("numinp", i)]],
                          value = NULL,
                          label = NULL)
        })
      }
    })
```

None of these helped. Every time I remove the variable selected at first, the `new.recoding.values$values` is printed as `NULL` in the console, but then adding another variable `new.recoding.values$values` suddenly recovers the first values entered first, like it still "remembers" the first input.

I don't really understand this behavior can someone help to overcome this, i.e. really update on variable change?

Comment: what is your end goal here? there might be a better way to do it. You want to have user change the factors in the original table?

Comment: short version is that you have to use `updateTextInput` to remove the values from the `session` as well. Otherwise you just remove them from the user interface. Digging through your code is a bit cumbersome as it is not really minimal. But you would identify which column was removed and apply `updateTextInput` for the corresponding textinputs.

Comment: @Tonio Yes, sorry for the lengthy code, I tried to be as specific and detailed as possible. I edited the post, following your advice, except that I thought it is not the columns that were removed that have to be taken into account (this actually failed), but the user-entered values. Still, it does not update them. Can you help with this, I am really suffering with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `textFields` are created within the `datatable`, you need to unbind before you use the table again (`updateTextInput` doesn't work). Using the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63073557/render-dropdown-for-single-column-in-dt-shiny-but-loaded-only-on-cell-click-and/63118763#63118763) answer, I added the JS script with the unbind function and the function is called in the observer for the left arrow. Then you get a working app:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(data.table)
library(shinyFiles)


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(
    HTML(
      "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('unbindDT', function(id) {
        var $table = $('#'+id).find('table');
        if($table.length > 0){
          Shiny.unbindAll($table.DataTable().table().node());
        }
      })")
  )),
  
  shinyFilesButton(id = "recodeChooseSrcFile", label = "Choose data file", title = "Navigate and select a file", multiple = FALSE),
  
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 6,
           DTOutput(outputId = "recodeAllAvailableVars"),
    ),
    column(width = 1, align = "center",
           br(), br(), br(), br(), br(), br(), br(), br(), br(), br(),
           uiOutput(outputId = "recodeArrowSelVarsRight"),
           br(), br(),
           uiOutput(outputId = "recodeArrowSelVarsLeft"),
    ),
    column(width = 5,
           DTOutput(outputId = "recodeVarsSelection"),
    ),
    br(), br()
  ),
  
  br(), br(),
  DTOutput(outputId = "recodeScheme")
  
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  available.volumes <- getVolumes()()
  
  file.var.recode <- reactiveValues(loaded = NULL, var.levels = NULL)
  
  # Select file and extract the variables.
  shinyFileChoose(input, "recodeChooseSrcFile", roots = available.volumes, filetype = list(RData = "RData"))
  
  observeEvent(eventExpr = input$recodeChooseSrcFile, {
    
    if(length(parseFilePaths(available.volumes, input$recodeChooseSrcFile)$datapath) > 0) {
      
      file.var.recode$loaded <- get(load(parseFilePaths(available.volumes, input$recodeChooseSrcFile)$datapath))
      
      file.var.recode$var.levels <- Filter(Negate(is.null), lapply(X = file.var.recode$loaded, FUN = function(i) {
        if(is.null(attr(x = i, which = "levels"))) {
          NULL
        } else {
          attr(x = i, which = "levels")
        }
      }))
      
      file.var.recode$loaded <- data.table(Variables = names(file.var.recode$loaded),
                                           
                                           order_col = 1:ncol(file.var.recode$loaded))
    }
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
  
  observe({
    
    var.props.initial.available.vars <- data.table(Variables = as.character(), order_col = as.numeric())
    var.props.initial.selected.vars <- data.table(Variables = as.character(), order_col = as.numeric())
    
    recodeAllVars <- reactiveValues(recodeAvailVars = var.props.initial.available.vars, recodeSelectedVars = var.props.initial.selected.vars)
    
    # Observe if the file is loaded, and if yes, update the table of available variables.
    observe({
      if(!is.null(file.var.recode$loaded)) {
        recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars <- file.var.recode$loaded
      }
    })
    
    # Render the arrow buttons for selecting the variables.
    output$recodeArrowSelVarsRight <- renderUI({
      if(is.null(file.var.recode$loaded)) {
        return(NULL)
      } else {
        actionButton(inputId = "recodeArrowSelVarsRight", label = NULL, icon("angle-right"), width = "50px")
      }
    })
    
    output$recodeArrowSelVarsLeft <- renderUI({
      if(is.null(file.var.recode$loaded)) {
        return(NULL)
      } else {
        actionButton(inputId = "recodeArrowSelVarsLeft", label = NULL, icon("angle-left"), width = "50px")
      }
    })
    
    # Render the data table with the available variables.
    output$recodeAllAvailableVars <- renderDT({
      
      if(is.null(file.var.recode$loaded)) {
        return(NULL)
      } else {
        setkeyv(x = recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars, cols = "order_col")
      }
      
    },
    caption = "Available variables",
    rownames = FALSE,
    colnames = c("Names", "sortingcol"),
    options = list(
      ordering = FALSE,
      columnDefs = list(list(visible = FALSE, targets = 1))
    ))
    
    
    
    # Render the table with the selected variables.
    output$recodeVarsSelection <- renderDT({
      if(is.null(file.var.recode$loaded)) {
        return(NULL)
      } else {
        setkeyv(x = recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars, cols = "order_col")
      }
    },
    
    caption = "Available variables",
    rownames = FALSE,
    colnames = c("Names", "sortingcol"),
    options = list(
      ordering = FALSE,
      columnDefs = list(list(visible = FALSE, targets = 1))
      
    ))
    
    # Observe the events of moving variables from available to selected.
    observeEvent(input$recodeArrowSelVarsRight, {
      req(input$recodeAllAvailableVars_rows_selected)
      recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars <- rbind(isolate(recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars), recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars[input$recodeAllAvailableVars_rows_selected, , drop = F])
      recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars <- recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars[complete.cases(recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars[ , "Variables"]), , drop = FALSE]
      recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars <- isolate(recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars[-input$recodeAllAvailableVars_rows_selected, , drop = F])
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$recodeArrowSelVarsLeft, {
      req(input$recodeVarsSelection_rows_selected)
      recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars <- rbind(isolate(recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars), recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars[input$recodeVarsSelection_rows_selected, , drop = F])
      recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars <- recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars[complete.cases(recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars[ , "Variables"]), , drop = FALSE]
      recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars <- isolate(recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars[-input$recodeVarsSelection_rows_selected, , drop = F])
      session$sendCustomMessage("unbindDT", "recodeScheme")
    })
    
    # Render the table with the text inputs.
    initial.recode.new.values <- reactiveValues(values = NULL)
    
    entered.new.values <- reactiveValues(values = NULL)
    
    new.recoding.values <- reactiveValues(values = NULL)
    
    shinyInput <- function(obj) {
      tmp <- unlist(lapply(X = seq_along(obj), FUN = function(i) {
        i <- paste0(textInput(inputId = paste0("numinp", i), label = NULL, value = NULL, width = "50px"))
      }))
      return(tmp)
    }
    
    shinyValue <- function(id, len) {
      unlist(lapply(seq_len(len), function(i) {
        input[[paste0(id, i)]]
      }))
    }
    
    # Observe the changes in user selection and update the reactive values from above.
    observe({
      
      initial.recode.new.values$values <- unlist(unique(file.var.recode$var.levels[recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars[ , Variables]]))
      
      entered.new.values$values <- data.table(
        V1 = initial.recode.new.values$values,
        V2 = initial.recode.new.values$values,
        V3 = rep(x = "->", times = length(initial.recode.new.values$values)),
        V4 = shinyInput(unlist(unique(file.var.recode$var.levels[recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars[ , Variables]])))
      )
      
      new.recoding.values$values <- shinyValue(id = "numinp", len = length(unlist(unique(file.var.recode$var.levels[recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars[ , Variables]]))))
      
    })
    
    # Render the table with available levels and empty input fields where the user can enter his desired new values.
    output$recodeScheme <- renderDT({
      
      if(!is.null(unlist(unique(file.var.recode$var.levels[recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars[ , Variables]])))) {
        entered.new.values$values
      } else {
        return(NULL)
      }
      
    },
    rownames = FALSE,
    colnames = c("Available variable values", "Old", "->", "New"),
    class = "cell-border stripe;compact cell-border;",
    selection="none",
    escape = FALSE,
    options = list(
      pageLength = 1500,
      dom = 'BRrt',
      rowCallback = JS("function(r,d) {$(r).attr('height', '40px')}"),
      preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
      drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')))
    
    observe({
      print(new.recoding.values$values)
    })
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, I recommend you to read more about reactivity, e.g. [here](https://www.mastering-shiny.org). You use a lot of observers, and you nest them. I don't recommend that, because this can lead to strange behaviour. Also, try to use more `reactive`/`reactiveExpression`, because `observe`/`observeEvent` can make your app slower. Before I found the correct solution, I tried to unnest your code a bit, and it still works! That shows that you had complexity in your app you actually don't need:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(data.table)
library(shinyFiles)

# additional functions
shinyInput <- function(obj) {
    tmp <- unlist(lapply(X = seq_along(obj), FUN = function(i) {
        i <- paste0(textInput(inputId = paste0("numinp", i), label = NULL, value = NULL, width = "50px"))
    }))
    return(tmp)
}

shinyValue <- function(id, len, input) {
    unlist(lapply(seq_len(len), function(i) {
        input[[paste0(id, i)]]
    }))
}


ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$script(
        HTML(
            "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('unbindDT', function(id) {
        var $table = $('#'+id).find('table');
        if($table.length > 0){
          Shiny.unbindAll($table.DataTable().table().node());
        }
      })")
    )),
    shinyFilesButton(id = "recodeChooseSrcFile", label = "Choose data file", title = "Navigate and select a file", multiple = FALSE),
    
    fluidRow(
        column(width = 6,
               DTOutput(outputId = "recodeAllAvailableVars"),
        ),
        column(width = 1, align = "center",
               br(), br(), br(), br(), br(), br(), br(), br(), br(), br(),
               uiOutput(outputId = "recodeArrowSelVarsRight"),
               br(), br(),
               uiOutput(outputId = "recodeArrowSelVarsLeft"),
        ),
        column(width = 5,
               DTOutput(outputId = "recodeVarsSelection"),
        ),
        br(), br()
    ),
    
    br(), br(),
    DTOutput(outputId = "recodeScheme")
    
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    available.volumes <- getVolumes()()
    
    file.var.recode <- reactiveValues(loaded = NULL, var.levels = NULL)
    
    # define variables
    # Render the table with the text inputs.
    initial.recode.new.values <- reactiveValues(values = NULL)
    
    entered.new.values <- reactiveValues(values = NULL)
    
    new.recoding.values <- reactiveValues(values = NULL)
    
    # Select file and extract the variables.
    shinyFileChoose(input, "recodeChooseSrcFile", roots = available.volumes, filetype = list(RData = "RData"))
    
    observeEvent(eventExpr = input$recodeChooseSrcFile, {
        
        if(length(parseFilePaths(available.volumes, input$recodeChooseSrcFile)$datapath) > 0) {
            
            file.var.recode$loaded <- get(load(parseFilePaths(available.volumes, input$recodeChooseSrcFile)$datapath))
            
            file.var.recode$var.levels <- Filter(Negate(is.null), lapply(X = file.var.recode$loaded, FUN = function(i) {
                if(is.null(attr(x = i, which = "levels"))) {
                    NULL
                } else {
                    attr(x = i, which = "levels")
                }
            }))
            
            file.var.recode$loaded <- data.table(Variables = names(file.var.recode$loaded),
                                                 
                                                 order_col = 1:ncol(file.var.recode$loaded))
        }
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
    
    recodeAllVars <- reactiveValues(recodeAvailVars = data.table(Variables = as.character(), order_col = as.numeric()),
                                    recodeSelectedVars = data.table(Variables = as.character(), order_col = as.numeric()))
    
    
    # Observe if the file is loaded, and if yes, update the table of available variables.
    observe({
        if(!is.null(file.var.recode$loaded)) {
            recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars <- file.var.recode$loaded
        }
    })
    
    # Render the arrow buttons for selecting the variables.
    output$recodeArrowSelVarsRight <- renderUI({
        if(is.null(file.var.recode$loaded)) {
            return(NULL)
        } else {
            actionButton(inputId = "recodeArrowSelVarsRight", label = NULL, icon("angle-right"), width = "50px")
        }
    })
    
    output$recodeArrowSelVarsLeft <- renderUI({
        if(is.null(file.var.recode$loaded)) {
            return(NULL)
        } else {
            actionButton(inputId = "recodeArrowSelVarsLeft", label = NULL, icon("angle-left"), width = "50px")
        }
    })
    
    # Render the data table with the available variables.
    output$recodeAllAvailableVars <- renderDT({
        
        if(is.null(file.var.recode$loaded)) {
            return(NULL)
        } else {
            setkeyv(x = recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars, cols = "order_col")
        }
        
    },
    caption = "Available variables",
    rownames = FALSE,
    colnames = c("Names", "sortingcol"),
    options = list(
        ordering = FALSE,
        columnDefs = list(list(visible = FALSE, targets = 1))
    ))
    
    # Render the table with the selected variables.
    output$recodeVarsSelection <- renderDT({
        if(is.null(file.var.recode$loaded)) {
            return(NULL)
        } else {
            setkeyv(x = recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars, cols = "order_col")
        }
    },
    
    caption = "Available variables",
    rownames = FALSE,
    colnames = c("Names", "sortingcol"),
    options = list(
        ordering = FALSE,
        columnDefs = list(list(visible = FALSE, targets = 1))
        
    ))
    
    # Observe the events of moving variables from available to selected.
    observeEvent(input$recodeArrowSelVarsRight, {
        req(input$recodeAllAvailableVars_rows_selected)
        recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars <- rbind(isolate(recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars), recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars[input$recodeAllAvailableVars_rows_selected, , drop = F])
        recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars <- recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars[complete.cases(recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars[ , "Variables"]), , drop = FALSE]
        recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars <- isolate(recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars[-input$recodeAllAvailableVars_rows_selected, , drop = F])
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$recodeArrowSelVarsLeft, {
        req(input$recodeVarsSelection_rows_selected)
        recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars <- rbind(isolate(recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars), recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars[input$recodeVarsSelection_rows_selected, , drop = F])
        recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars <- recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars[complete.cases(recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars[ , "Variables"]), , drop = FALSE]
        recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars <- isolate(recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars[-input$recodeVarsSelection_rows_selected, , drop = F])
        
        session$sendCustomMessage("unbindDT", "recodeScheme")
    })
    
    # Observe the changes in user selection and update the reactive values from above.
    observe({
        
        initial.recode.new.values$values <- unlist(unique(file.var.recode$var.levels[recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars[ , Variables]]))
        
        entered.new.values$values <- data.table(
            V1 = initial.recode.new.values$values,
            V2 = initial.recode.new.values$values,
            V3 = rep(x = "->", times = length(initial.recode.new.values$values)),
            V4 = shinyInput(unlist(unique(file.var.recode$var.levels[recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars[ , Variables]])))
        )
        
        new.recoding.values$values <- shinyValue(id = "numinp",
                                                 len = length(unlist(unique(file.var.recode$var.levels[recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars[ , Variables]]))),
                                                 input = input)
        
    })
    
    # Render the table with available levels and empty input fields where the user can enter his desired new values.
    output$recodeScheme <- renderDT({
        
        if(!is.null(unlist(unique(file.var.recode$var.levels[recodeAllVars$recodeSelectedVars[ , Variables]])))) {
            entered.new.values$values
        } else {
            return(NULL)
        }
        
    },
    rownames = FALSE,
    colnames = c("Available variable values", "Old", "->", "New"),
    class = "cell-border stripe;compact cell-border;",
    selection="none",
    escape = FALSE,
    options = list(
        pageLength = 1500,
        dom = 'BRrt',
        rowCallback = JS("function(r,d) {$(r).attr('height', '40px')}"),
        preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
        drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')))
    
    observe({
        print(new.recoding.values$values)
    })
    
    
    
    # end of server
}



shinyApp(ui, server)
```

There is still some room for improvement, e.g. you could try to use a `reactive` instead of `observe` for the following snippet:

```
    # Observe if the file is loaded, and if yes, update the table of available variables.
    observe({
        if(!is.null(file.var.recode$loaded)) {
            recodeAllVars$recodeAvailVars <- file.var.recode$loaded
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time and effort not only to solve it, but also to optimize my code, I really appreciate this. You are right I should have  used less observers without nesting them, still new to Shiny and have a lot to learn. Thank you for the source provided as well.

Comment: I have an additional question about the javascript code you provided at the beginning and using it to unbind the table through calling it via `session$sendCustomMessage("unbindDT", "recodeScheme")`. I don't know javascript, but do I understand correctly that the script in the beginning is generic and can be used to unbind other elements in the `DT`s in the app by pointing to the `DT` (`recodeScheme` in this case). Would it unbind all dynamically generated inputs in this table? Say I put inside not only text inputs, but add `selectInput` on each row as well?

Comment: I'm not great with JS either, but yes the function is generic and can be used for other tables as well. For the second part: I think it should work, but I'm not completely sure. As I said, I've used the solution from the linked answer by @Stéphane Laurent, he's the expert on shiny + JS

Comment: This is helpful, thank you very much! Still a lot to learn.