# How to adjust the width of selected columns in datatable (DT)

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

I am trying to adjust the width of datatable DT in shiny which works for the below simple example -

```
library(magrittr)
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput('dt')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$dt <- DT::renderDataTable({
    dt1 <- head(mtcars)
    
    DT::datatable(dt1, rownames = FALSE) %>% 
      DT::formatStyle(columns = c(3,6), width='200px')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

However, my actual datatable is bit complicated and has some javascript functions.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput('dt', width = '700px')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  shinyInput = function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
    inputs = character(len)
    for (i in seq_len(len)) {
      inputs[i] = as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), label = NULL, ...))
    }
    inputs
  }
  
  output$dt<- DT::renderDataTable({
    dt1 <- head(mtcars)
    df <- cbind(select = shinyInput(shiny::checkboxInput, nrow(dt1), 'check'),dt1)
    
    DT::datatable(df, selection = 'none', escape = FALSE,options = list(
      preDrawCallback = htmlwidgets::JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
      drawCallback = htmlwidgets::JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } '))) %>%
      DT::formatStyle(columns = c(3,6), width='200px')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I copied the `shinyInput` function from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50178470/16024709).

But now `formatStyle` does not work on this and no width is changed. I want to give different width to every column manually especially reduce the width of the first column with checkbox (`select`) which takes up lot of space.

[image]

Do you have any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass `width` value to `shiny::checkboxInput` :

```
df <- cbind(select = shinyInput(shiny::checkboxInput, nrow(dt1), 'check', width = '10px'),dt1)
```

[image]

Complete app code -

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput('dt', width = '700px')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  shinyInput = function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
    inputs = character(len)
    for (i in seq_len(len)) {
      inputs[i] = as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), label = NULL, ...))
    }
    inputs
  }
  
  output$dt<- DT::renderDataTable({
    dt1 <- head(mtcars)
    df <- cbind(select = shinyInput(shiny::checkboxInput, nrow(dt1), 'check', width = '10px'),dt1)
    
    DT::datatable(df, selection = 'none', escape = FALSE,options = list(
      preDrawCallback = htmlwidgets::JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
      drawCallback = htmlwidgets::JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } '))) %>%
      DT::formatStyle(columns = c(3,6), width='200px')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is taken from one of my apps, hope it helps

```r
DT::datatable(
  data = data,
  options = list(
    columnDefs = list(
      list(width = "10%", class = "dt-right", targets = 4)
    )
  )
)
```

The thing is that you can pass options as a list in `columnDefs`. That particular option is saying that the fifth column (index starts in 0) has class `dt-right` (to right-align the content) and its width is 10% of the table. You can pass a vector with more than one element in `targets`.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. It does align the contents to the right but it does not reduce the width of `select` column. I tried with `list(width = "10%", class = "dt-right", targets = c(0, 1))`. The width of it remains as it is.

Comment: Looks like @Ronak Shah answer solves your problem